# document.getElementById.innerHTML= Radio Buttons?

Tags: javascript

I am making a quiz in JavaScript that randomly selects 10 questions from a list of 20.  My code says:

```
if (question==1){
    document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 1"
}
```

My problem is that my final quiz will not say "Question 1."  I want it to write radio buttons for a multiple choice.  How can I replace "Question 1" with radio buttons?

Also, I don't want my code to pull the same question more than once.  example:  So they don't answer question 4 twice.  Here is my full code:

```
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Start!" onclick="choosequestions()"/><br><br>
    <div id="1"></div><br>
    <div id="2"></div><br>
    <div id="3"></div><br>
    <div id="4"></div><br>
    <div id="5"></div><br>
    <div id="6"></div><br>
    <div id="7"></div><br>
    <div id="8"></div><br>
    <div id="9"></div><br>
    <div id="10"></div><br>
<body>
<script>
    function choosequestions(){
        for(q=1;q < 11;q++){
            var question=Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1)
            if (question==1){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 1"    
            }else if (question==2){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 2"
            }else if (question==3){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 3"
            }else if (question==4){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 4"
            }else if (question==5){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 5"
            }else if (question==6){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 6"
            }else if (question==7){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 7"
            }else if (question==8){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 8"
            }else if (question==9){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 9"
            }else if (question==10){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 10"
            }else if (question==11){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 11"
            }else if (question==12){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 12"
            }else if (question==13){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 13"
            }else if (question==14){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 14"
            }else if (question==15){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 15"
            }else if (question==16){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 16"
            }else if (question==17){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 17"
            }else if (question==18){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 18"
            }else if (question==19){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 19"
            }else if (question==20){
                document.getElementById(q).innerHTML="Question 20"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please make a JSFiddle and let me know...

Comment: This is what @FranciscoCorrales is talking about: [click here](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can simplify your function to this:

```
function choosequestions(){
    for(q=1; q < 11; q++){
        var question=Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1);
        document.getElementById(q).innerHTML = 'Question ' + question;
    }
}
```

Second, to make sure you don't have the same question being selected multiple times, do something like this:

```
function choosequestions(){
    var qList = [];
    for(q=1; q < 11; q++){
        var question = Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1);

        // Check to make sure Question # 'question' has not been added already:
        while (qList.indexOf(question) !== -1) {
            question = Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1);
        }
        qList.push(question);
        document.getElementById(q).innerHTML = 'Question ' + question;
    }
}
```

If you don't understand this function, let me know and I can explain.

Finally, to make the text go into a radio button, and use the function above, change to this:

```
function choosequestions(){
    var qList = [];
    for(q=1; q < 11; q++){
        var question = Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1);
        while (qList.indexOf(question) !== -1) {
            question = Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1);
        }
        qList.push(question);

        // Create radio button within each div element:
        document.getElementById(q).innerHTML = '<input type="radio" name="question" value="' + q + '">Question ' + question;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is helpful!

---

**Edit:** As per your comments, I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
function choosequestions(){
    var qList = [];
    for(q=1; q < 11; q++){
        var question = Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1);
        var message = '';
        while (qList.indexOf(question) !== -1) {
            question = Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1);
        }
        qList.push(question);

        // Create radio button within each div element:
        if (question==1){
            message = "Question 1";
        }else if (question==2){
            message = "Question 2";
        }
        ...
        // Lots of other 'else if' statements
        ...
        }else if (question==20){
            message = "Question 20";
        }
        document.getElementById(q).innerHTML = message;
    }
}
```

This way, you can still change the html thrown into each specific question div.

Comment: Tyrannical Tyrannosaurus, I would appreciate any explanation.  (I am only 14 years old and recently started teaching myself JavaScript, so I don't know a lot yet.)

Comment: Groovy, which parts specifically? BTW [this link](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript) is a great resource for learning JS.

Comment: I don't understand your second code.  Thanks for the link, I'm sure I'll learn a lot!

Comment: I don't think I can condense the function, because, my final code will look something like this:  



`else if (question==18){


document.getElementById(q).innerHTML= '<input id="country" type="radio" name="fav" value="country" />Country<br /> <input id="blues" type="radio" name="fav" value="blues" />Blues<br /> <input id="rock" type="radio" name="fav" value="rock" />Rock<br /> <input id="pop" type="radio" name="fav" value="pop" />Pop</form>'

} `

Comment: and then I need to use JS to check the answers as well.

Comment: For the second function: **1)** `var qList = [];` creates an empty array. **2)** you probably understand your for-loop & your `question` variable. **3)** `while (qList.indexOf(question) !== -1)` will check to see if your variable `question` is inside the array `qList`. If it is found, `.indexOf()` will return the index it was found at, so `qList.indexOf(question)` will NOT equal -1. **4)** In this case, the `question` variable will randomize again and keep looping through the `while` until it becomes a variable NOT inside `qList`.

Comment: **5)** `qList.push(question);` adds the variable `question` to the array `qList`. This is necessary so that on the next for-loop iteration we can check to make sure the `question` variable is not repeated.

Comment: As for adding your condition for `question == 18`, will you have many questions with specific innerHTML strings to give? Or will there be mostly one common string with a few odd questions? It is always possible to do the simplification above, but exclude a few circumstances like: `if (question == 18) { ... code ... } else if (question == something-else) { ... code ... } else { ... simplified innerHTML code ... }`. Does that make sense?

Comment: They will be completely different questions, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Check my edit. I added back in the ability to change specific question text / html.

Comment: Yes, @TyrannicalTyrannosaurus.  That fixed my issue.  I have another question (sorry) that can be found at the following link, if you don't mind helping.  [click here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/21690516/how-to-add-a-string-to-a-variable-inside-an-input-tag)