# How to add a string to a variable inside an <input> tag?

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I am going to use JavaScript to create and grade a quiz.  It has 20 questions, and randomly selects 10 of them for the quiz.  What I need help with is found in the REALLY long line below.  See where it says id="q + correct"? This Id will be used in grading the quiz to see if it's checked.  variable "q" contains the number (from 1 to 10) that is was randomly chosen for the quiz.  Example: If q=1 (it was picked first for the quiz), I will use `document.getElementById('1correct').checked` to see if it is selected.  However, I don't know how to join the variable "q" to the string "correct" in this context.  I'd appreciate any answers.

```
function choosequestions(){
    var qList = [];
    for(q=1; q < 11; q++){
        var question = Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1);
        while (qList.indexOf(question) !== -1) {
            question = Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1);
        }
        qList.push(question);

        if (question==1){
            document.getElementById(q).innerHTML='Question '+ q +'.  Which of these freedoms are protected in the 1st amendment?<br /><br /><input id="q + correct" type="radio" name="fav" value="country" />Freedoms of Religion, Speech and Petition.<br /> <input id="q + .2" type="radio" name="fav" value="blues" />Right to bear arms.<br /> <input id="q + .3" type="radio" name="fav" value="rock" />Right to \"Life, liberty, and the pursuit of happiness.\"<br /> <input id="q + .4" type="radio" name="fav" value="pop" />All of the above.</form>'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, the single apostrophes `''` and the double apostrophes `""` are both used for strings, but can be used separately.

Just as you added the first `q` variable into the html with:

```
document.getElementById(q).innerHTML = 'Question ' + q + '... rest of string';
```

You will need to break the string, add the variable `q`, and add the rest of the string back in. This will need to be done in multiple parts of your innerHTML string, not just where `'correct'` occurs.

Here is a simpler look at the text you should be inserting:

```
document.getElementById(q).innerHTML = 'Question '+ q +
    '.  Which of these freedoms are protected in the 1st amendment?<br /><br />' +
    '<input id="' + q + 'correct" type="radio" name="fav" value="country" />Freedoms of Religion, Speech and Petition.<br />' + 
    '<input id="' + q + '.2" type="radio" name="fav" value="blues" />Right to bear arms.<br />' + 
    '<input id="' + q + '.3" type="radio" name="fav" value="rock" />Right to \"Life, liberty, and the pursuit of happiness.\"<br />' + 
    '<input id="' + q + '.4" type="radio" name="fav" value="pop" />All of the above.</form>';
```

Notice that you have to do the same thing with the `id` for inputs `'correct'`, `'.2'`, `'.3'` and `'.4'`.

Comment: I am having a little trouble with my function that checks which radio box is selected.  Could you help @TyrannicalTyrannosaurus?  The JS can be found here: http://js.do/ianhazzard/31112

Comment: Awesome! Fo sho - it looks like you missed one `"` mark for the `onClick` in your second input (line 8) :D

Answer (score 1):

Because the long string is encapsulated with apostrophes, you should be able to do it like this:

```
    '<input id="' + q + 'correct" type="radio" name="fav" value="country" />'
```